# How can I make this multiplication much simpler with pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to multiply two matrix like this(scalar multiplication).
But this method looks dumb. How can I make this much simpler?

```
A.size # B * S * V
B.size # B

A * B.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).expand_as(A)
```

Comment: `A`'s dimensions `S` and `V` are guaranteed to be 1? And what is `local_KB`?

Comment: @dennlinger no~~!!

Comment: Can't you simply do `A*B`? I tried for some matrices, and it worked for me. If that is not your desired result, please provide a concrete example where you get a wrong result and have to resort to the `unsqueeze()` method.

Comment: Explicitly calling `expand_as` should not be necessary as pytorch implements numpy's broadcasting rules. How about `A * B.view(-1, 1, 1)`?